# window.open and jquery load unload events in ie9+

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery, window.open

i'm stuck in a damn simple problem, this code is working well in firefox and chrome, events fires regularly, but for ie9+ no, they do not fires.

```
if (popup) {
  popup.close();
}

var features = "width=900,height=630,menubar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0";
popup = window.open("myJsp.jsp?" + new Date().getTime(), "_blank", features);

$(popup).on("load", function() {
  ...
}).on("unload", function() {
  ...
});
```

The popup displays correctly.

EDIT: the unload event works correctly.

EDIT: it seems that the load event does not fire because has already been fired by the opened windows (in IE)

Comment: I think you need to hook the load event up to the DOM of the popup, not the window itself.

Comment: can you post the whole code?

Comment: whole code? the only code i have is the myJsp that is an empty html document

Comment: In most browsers, `window.open` won't work unless it's inside a click handler.

Comment: It's inside a click handler

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I've also found the load event not firing in Internet Explorer.